# Installing a R package from git

Tags: r, scrnaseq

I am trying to install STEMNET R package but a permanent error stops me, what can I do please?

```
> > library(devtools)
> > devtools::install_git("https://git.embl.de/velten/STEMNET/", build_vignettes=TRUE) Downloading git repo
> https://git.embl.de/velten/STEMNET/ Installation failed: Error in
> 'git2r_clone': SSL error: syscall failure: Connection reset by peer
> 
> > 
> > devtools::install_git("https://git.embl.de/velten/STEMNET/", build_vignettes=FALSE) Downloading git repo
> https://git.embl.de/velten/STEMNET/ Installation failed: Error in
> 'git2r_clone': SSL error: syscall failure: Connection reset by peer
> 
> > 
> > library(git2r)
> 
> Attaching package: ‘git2r’
> 
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:Biobase’:
> 
>     content, notes
> 
> The following object is masked from ‘package:igraph’:
> 
>     tree
> 
> > 
> > libgit2_features function ()  {
>     .Call(git2r_libgit2_features) } <bytecode: 0x1d276d918> <environment: namespace:git2r>
> > devtools::install_git("https://git.embl.de/velten/STEMNET/", build_vignettes=FALSE) Downloading git repo
> https://git.embl.de/velten/STEMNET/ Installation failed: Error in
> 'git2r_clone': SSL error: syscall failure: Connection reset by peer
> 
> > 
> > install_git("c97sr/idd") Downloading git repo c97sr/idd Installation failed: Error in 'git2r_clone': unsupported URL protocol
> 
> > 
> > install_git() Error in lapply(url, git_remote, subdir = subdir, branch = branch, credentials = credentials) :    argument "url" is
> missing, with no default
> >
```

Comment: I wonder if you have an issue with your SSL library or the server was down, I've just installed the STEMNET package and all dependencies on my mac without problem I'm using R 3.5.1 and High Sierra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UPDATE 2018/04/22: Some users had problem with this command, a way to
>   install that works for everyone is to download the tar.gz archive,
>   unpack to a directory of your choice (e.g. /path/to) and inside R run
>   devtools::install_local("/path/to/stemnet_dir", build_vignettes=T)

https://git.embl.de/velten/STEMNET

Comment: Sorry but my problem is this I don't know from where download the  tar.gz archive, do you know?

Comment: https://git.embl.de/velten/STEMNET/-/archive/master/STEMNET-master.tar.gz